# Search query trouble

Tags: php

i have a function for a very simple search script but is does not seem to work and i just cant find the error even i might think is easy to see! to make it simple to understand i omitted the security!

```
public function listing() {
        if(isset($_POST['immoSearch']) && $_POST['immoSearch'] !== '') {
            $immoSearch = $_POST['immoSearch'];
            $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE `name` LIKE :search_string" );
            $sth->execute(array(':search_string' => '%$immoSearch%'));
            return $sth->fetchAll();
        }
}
```

Comment: Debugging skills are a *must* if you wish to be a programmer.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: "*to make it simple to understand i omitted the security!*" Do you want your site to get hacked? "Omitting security" is **never** a good idea.

Comment: Hint: "Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will *not* be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.", cf. [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: im getting nothing! and sorry if the question isnt usefull am new to all this, but thanks for a very fast reaction

Comment: But what does *nothing* mean? You can be new to all this but you can also provide in-depth detail to help us troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Thanks you guys Dennis just got it down there, and ill take care next time while giving info so that you can help easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query here will read:

```
SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE `name` LIKE %$immoSearch%
```

**Fixed**

```
public function listing() {

    if(isset($_POST['immoSearch']) && $_POST['immoSearch'] !== '') {


        $immoSearch = $_POST['immoSearch'];
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE `name` LIKE :search_string" );
        $sth->execute(array(':search_string' => "%{$immoSearch}%"));
        return $sth->fetchAll();


        }

}
```

EDIT:
Note that the line with the execute method now uses double quotes.

Comment: thanks that was it, that is embarrassing that i couldnt see it, thanks again! and yes the double quotes where missing too